# Encrypt using Python and decrypt in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, encryption

I have some JSON data that I need to encrypt before sending it to the client side. I can encrypt the data using pycrpto like this:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
key = '0123456789abcdef'
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
encryptor = AES.new(key, mode)
text = jsonData
ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(text)
```

And then I can send it to the client side. Now I need to use jQuery/Javascript to convert the ciphertext to plain text. [jsaes](http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/) is an implementation of AES in Javascript. Can it be used to decrypt data back to plain text? Or is there any other library I can use to complete this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to decrypt it using any implementation of AES, just make sure you use the same `mode` that you used to encrypt it (in this case Cipher Block Chain or CBC)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29

Also PyCrypto, while good, might be a little bit too low level for you. You might want to look at using something like GPGME for Python: http://pyme.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Your straight forward answer is what Wes said.

However, there are problems of transmitting the key securely. (One could use a private/public key mechanism but then, there's no point encrypting the data because you already a P/P mechanism)

SSL/HTTPS were created for secure "transactions" between client and server, I would advise you use those.

Comment: With the current formulation this is more of a comment. I'd reformulate it a bit, so it's more of an answer.

Comment: @CodeInChaos OK - re-writing now.

Comment: I would give you a +1 for your answer.